# JNA Equivalent for C Code

Tags: java, jna

I have a C code segment like this

```
struct test{
char *ptr;
}
```

What is the equivalent JNA Syntax?

Comment: You want to access test from Java via JNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as straight forward as;

```
public class test extends Structure {
  String ptr;
}
```

More about `char*` mapping [here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/Mappings.md) and
`struct` mapping [here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/StructuresAndUnions.md).